# UIBarButtonItem not reacting after click

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

From the `rootViewController` I navigate to a `UIViewController`

```
if (self.contr == nil) {
    ExampleViewController *controller = [[ExampleViewController alloc] 
                                   initWithNibName:@"Example" 
                                   bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.contr = controller;
    [controller release];
}
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.contr animated:YES];
```

In the UIViewController I have the method

```
-(IBAction) goBack:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I added the signature to the .h file.
In the `.xib` file, I have a `UIToolbar` with a `UIBarButtonItem`. I connected the button to the File's Owner - `goBack`:

Everything appears in the screen, but when I click on the button, `goBack` isn't called. I also tried to do this programatically instead, but I got the same result - everything appears, but no reaction to the click.

Any ideas why it isn't working?

**Edit:**
I just found out something invisible is over the toolbar. If I click on a specific point (over the toolbar), then goBack: is called. Since I navigated to this screen using presentModelViewController, the navigation bar isn't appearing... but probably it's there and that's what is hiding the tool bar.

Comment: @Adriana Post Button declaration code

Comment: Add a line to Check if sender == UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Have you tried inserting a call to `NSLog` in the `goBack` method, or to set inside it a breakpoint to see if it is not called or if it has no effect?

Comment: I put a breakpoint at goBack: and I don't reach it...

Comment: Which event did you bind the action to?

Comment: In a UIBarButtonItem, I can't bind it to an event like in UIButton. I can just set the target and action. However, it should call the method it is binded to, when clicking.

Comment: Did you try NSLogging in -(IBAction) goBack:(id)sender ? Does the control go there ?

Comment: I found the problem, but I didn't find a solution: since I'm calling the presentModelViewController, the UINavigationItem in the top doesn't appear. However, it is there and it's over the toolbar I created. Please read "Edit" in my question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have bind your Toolbar with File Owner?
As your UIBarButton is subview of UIToolbar so you have to bind Toolbar with File Owner.

Comment: The toolbar is inside the view, and the view is binded to the file's owner. Anyway, I created an IBOutlet UIToolbar and bind it to see if it would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Comment: It's a subclass of UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Presenting a modal view controller do not require you to pass through a `UINavigationController`. I suggest you to change this:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.contr animated:YES];
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.contr animated:YES];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the goBack method :

```
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not hitting the breakpoint that means you did not connect them properly in the xib.